# Is it possible to bypass CCPA using EULA

Tags: california, ccpa

Is it possible to avoid CCPA by using an EULA that explicitly bans users with residence location or relation  to California?
By writing that the app is not intended to target californians and that they are not allowed I am no longer targeting californians nor am I offering services to them which means CCPA should not apply.In case they breach this I should get money from them as the person suffers fines(damages) because of the user so he must pay for it under breach of contract.

Comment: Are you _also_ blocking them by other means, or just burying a "no Californians please" in the EULA?

Comment: Geo blocking + no Californians + terms of use says app piracy not allowed

Answer (score 1):

### No

The [law](https://oag.ca.gov/privacy/ccpa) applies to all residents of California dealing with all businesses that meet the criteria.

You cannot contract outside the law so any provision in your EULA that attempted to exclude the law would be void and the existence of such a clause could possibly put you in breech of laws prohibiting misleading and deceptive conduct.

> Businesses cannot make you waive these rights, and any contract provision that says you waive these rights is unenforceable.

While you could, in theory, refuse to deal with Californians, that faces a number of difficulties:

- it applies to Californians no matter where they are so geolocation is a bust (without even considering the widespread use of VPNs)
- if you ask, and a Californian lies; well, they are in breach of contract but you are in breach of the law. The State of California doesn’t care if they lied when they prosecute you.
- people move. I live in Australia, but I could move to California in a month or a year. Then the law applies to me even if I signed up with you today.
- even if you can successfully exclude Californians, you are still stuck with pretty much the same obligations under GDPR for any Europeans who sneak in.

Frankly, the cost of compliance is likely to be substantially less than the cost of avoiding.

Comment: This surprises me; can I seriously provide a company information stating I live elsewhere, wait for them to breach the obligations they would have followed if they knew where I lived, then jump out and say "surprise, I actually live in California, you broke the law!" and get them (hypothetically) prosecuted?

Comment: But voilation of terms of service means I get right to hold data for performance of contract. On top of that these laws only apply to those who targeted EU or California so how will they apply  to me. Secondly you say cost of compliance    is less . If I use a payments provider who breaches CCPA  I will have to pay fine which can be hudreads if not millions of millions.

Comment: @astackexchangeuser why do you think who you target matters? The law doesn’t say that.

Comment: @RyanM no you can’t. But California can. Let’s say I tell you I’m 21 and you sell my liquor- if I’m 19, you’ve broken the law.

Comment: Then what is the SAFEGAURD FOR ALL THESE COMPANIES. SO what about (just naming one) Super Cel  which just requires all users to be below 13.